# In Ruby, how can I merge consecutive tokens in an array subject to a condition?

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge

This is with Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings and I want to fuse consecutive elements if they begin or end with a special character.  So, for instance, if my special character is "&" and I have an array

```
["a &", "b", "c", "d"]
```

I want the result to be

```
["a & b", "c", "d"]
```

Similarly, if the array is

```
["a", "&", "b", "c"]
```

I want the result to be

```
["a & b", "c"]
```

And if the array is

```
["a", "& b", "c"]
```

I want the result to be

```
["a & b", "c"]
```

However, if the array is

```
["&", "b", "c"]
```

The result should be

```
["&", "b", "c"]
```

because there is no non-special element preceding my special character.  So I have tried this as a solution

```
2.4.0 :012 >   words = ["a", "&", "b", "d"]
 => ["a", "&", "b", "d"]
2.4.0 :013 > SPECIAL_TOKENS = %w(&).freeze
 => ["&"]
2.4.0 :014 > words = words.chunk_while { |i, _| i.end_with?(*SPECIAL_TOKENS) }.map(&:join)
 => ["a", "&b", "d"]
```

but as you can see, it is not fusing the first element in with the rest (also I'm losing a space between the "&" and the "b").  Are there any adjustments I can make to the above to make it work as I expect?

Comment: Why are you using `end_with?` when your second item *begins* with `&`?

Comment: Just one pointer for this: Given you want the 2 elements `["a", "& b"]` to end up as an element `"a & b"` (i.e. with an extra space) you're going to need to be able to modify the elements too. So this isn't going to be achievable using just `chunk_while`. Maybe try writing some pseudo code to describe how this should work and then write that in Ruby and then once you've got something that works you could ask for tips on making it more idiomatic?

Comment: What about `['a', '& b &', 'c']`? `['a', '& b', '&c']`?

Comment: ,,,and `['a', '&', 'b', '&', 'c']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to do that. I assume that, as in the examples, no element (string) of the array begins or ends with a space.

**#1**

```
def join_some(arr, join_ch='&')
  arr.drop(1).each_with_object([arr.first]).with_index(1) do |(s,a),i|
    if (s[0] == join_ch && (i < arr.size - 1 || s.size > 1)) || 
       (a.last[-1] == join_ch && (i > 1 || a.last.size > 1)) 
      a.last << " #{s}"
    else
      a << s
    end
  end
end

join_some ["a", "&", "b", "d"]      #=> ["a & b", "d"]
join_some ["a", "& b", "c"]         #=> ["a & b", "c"]
join_some ["&", "b", "c"]           #=> ["&", "b", "c"]
join_some ["a", "b", "&"]           #=> ["a", "b", "&"]
join_some ["a", "&", "b", "&", "c"] #=> ["a & b & c"]
join_some ["a", "& b &", "c"]       #=> ["a & b & c"]
join_some ["&", "& b", "c"]         #=> ["& & b", "c"]
join_some [" &", "b", "c"]          #=> [" & b", "c"]
join_some ["&", "&", "&"]           #=> ["& & &"]
join_some ["a", "+ b", "+ c"], "+"  #=> ["a + b + c"]
```

I am not certain if the return values from the last several examples are what is wanted.

**#2**

The first step is to `join(c)` all the elements of the array to form a single string, where `c` is a character that is not present in any element of the array. (I elected to use `0.chr #=> x00`.) We can then use a regular expression `r` to `split(r)` the string as desired.

```
def join_some(arr, join_ch='&')
  split_ch = 0.chr
  r = /(?<=\A.|[^#{join_ch}])#{split_ch}(?=[^#{join_ch}]|.\z)/
  arr.join(split_ch).split(r).map { |s| s.tr(split_ch, ' ') }
end
```

This method gives the same results as the first method for the 10 examples given above. The regular expression is expressed below in *free-spacing* mode with explanatory comments. Here `join_ch #=> "&"` and `split_ch #=> \x00`.

```
r = /
    (?<=            # begin positive lookbehind
      \A            # match the beginning of the string
      .             # match any char
      |             # or
      [^#{join_ch}] # match any char other than the join char
    )               # end positive lookbehind
    #{split_ch}     # match split char
    (?=             # begin a positive lookahead
      [^#{join_ch}] # match any char other than the join char
      |             # or
      .             # match any char
      \z            # match end of the string
    )               # end positive lookahead
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode
  #=> (?<=          # begin positive lookbehind
  #     \A          # match the beginning of the string
  #     .           # match any char
  #     |           # or
  #     [^&]        # match any char other than the join char
  #   )             # end positive lookbehind
  #   \x00          # match split char
  #   (?=           # begin a positive lookahead
  #     [^&]        # match any char other than the join char
  #     |           # or
  #     .           # match any char
  #     \z          # match end of the string
  #   )             # end positive lookahead
  #   /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty long-winded but passes your tests. The method takes an array and a special-character as arguments. The initial `join.split.reject.map` 'standardises' the arrays into stripped single-elements, apart from the special-characters which have spaces either side. We then apply [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) twice.

```
def chunky arr, char
  char = "\\".concat char
  arr.join(' ')
     .split(/(\w)/)
     .reject { |s| s.strip.empty? }
     .map { |e| e.match?(' &') ? ' & ': e }
     .chunk_while { |a,b| a.match?(/\s#{char}\s/) && b.match?(/\w/) }
     .map(&:join)
     .chunk_while { |a,b| a.match?(/\w/) && b.match?(/\s#{char}\s\w/) }
     .map { |s| s.join.strip }
end

p chunky ["a &", "b", "c", "d"], '&'
 #=> ["a & b", "c", "d"]
p chunky ["a", "-", "b", "c"], '-'
 #=> ["a - b", "c"]
p chunky ["a", "+ b", "c"], '+'
 #=> ["a + b", "c"]
p chunky ["*", "b", "c"], '*'
 #=> ["*", "b", "c"]
p chunky ["a", "b", "&"], '&'
 #=> ["a", "b", "&"]
p chunky ["a", "b", "& c"], '&'
 #=> ["a", "b & c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution doesn't use special characters and, in my opinion, is the least surprising, it

- ignores extra trailing &s at the beginning or end of a string
- leaves consecutive (separate) &s alone (maybe you want to insert something between them)
- works with &&, &&&, &hello&, ...

Code:

```
def join_strings array, s = '&'
  array = array.flat_map {|i| i.match(Regexp.new"(?:^ *(?:\\#{s} )*(\\#{s})(?:\\#{s} )* *$)|(?:^ *(?:(\\#{s}) )*(.*?)(?: (\\#{s}))* *$)")[1..4]} - [nil]
  i = 0
  while i < array.length - 2
    if array[i..i+2].map {|i| i == s} == [false, true, false]
      array[i] = array[i..i+2].join ' '
      array.slice!(i + 1, 2)
    else i += 1 end
  end
  array
end
```

Results:

```
["1 &", "2", "3"]
  # => ["1 & 2", "3"]
["1", "& 2", "3"]
  # => ["1 & 2", "3"]
["1", "&", "2", "3"]
  # => ["1 & 2", "3"]
["&", "b", "c"]
  # => ["&", "b", "c"]
["a", "b", "&"]
  # => ["a", "b", "&"]
["a", "&", "b", "&", "c"]
  # => ["a & b & c"]
["a", "& b &", "c"]
  # => ["a & b & c"]
["a &", "b", "& c"]
  # => ["a & b & c"]
["a &", "b &", "c &"]
  # => ["a & b & c", "&"]
["& a", "& b", "& c"]
  # => ["&", "a & b & c"]
["&", "&", "&"]
  # => ["&", "&", "&"]
["a", "&", "&", "&", "c"]
  # => ["a", "&", "&", "&", "c"]
["&", "&", "c"]
  # => ["&", "&", "c"]
["&", "&", "&", "c"]
  # => ["&", "&", "&", "c"]
["& c"]
  # => ["&", "c"]
["&& &", "&&&"]
  # => ["&& & &&&"]
["& & & & &"]
  # => ["&"]
["a", "& b & & c &", "d"]
  # => ["a & b & & c & d"]
["a +", "b", "+ c +", "d", "+"] # using "+"
  # => ["a + b + c + d", "+"]
```